# $\vert\mathbb{Q}^m\vert = \vert\mathbb{N}\vert$. Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To start with I'm not completely understand what $\mathbb{Q}^m$ is. Is it the number of all elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ that was taken to some power $m$?

To show that two sets have the same cardinality we must introduce a map $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}^m$ that would be a bijection, but I got stuck with it. Can someone please show me a proof or give a hint?

Comment: The set $\mathbb Q^m$ is the set of all sequences $(q_1, \ldots, q_m)$ where each $q_i$ is a rational number. (You may be more familiar with the set $\mathbb R^m$ -- the idea is the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an explicit bijection between $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$, see

[Produce an explicit bijection between rationals and naturals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals?noredirect=1&lq=1),

and an bijection between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}^m$, see

[Does There exist a continuous bijection $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476383/does-there-exist-a-continuous-bijection-mathbbq-to-mathbbq-times-mathbb?rq=1)

[Is $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q $ a denumerable set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664167/is-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-a-denumerable-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now compose the two bijections.

Comment: If your answer is just links to other questions, then perhaps the question is just a duplicate, and instead of writing an answer you should close it as such?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I agree. Which one of the three should I chose?

Comment: Since we can have multiple duplicate targets, why not all of them?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that multiple assigments are possible, thank you!